# Why there is no light in the home screen button of BLU Win HD?

Tags: display, blu-win-hd

I am wondering why there is no light in the three buttons of BLU Win HD phone? The home screen, the back and the search buttons have no light. In the dark, someone has to guest where is the button in order to press the right one.

I called the technical assistance and he/she said : "The phone is designed this way".

I bought this phone two weeks ago. It is a good phone but this "flaw" is somehow ridiculous.

Comment: Seems like you already have an answer to your question - the phone was not designed to have the buttons light up. Probably a cost-cutting measure. I'm wondering what you were hoping to gain from asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the light isn't there because of a cost-cutting measure. BLU Win HD isn't a top-of-the-line phone and things like these are to be expected. However, I'm sure you'll get used to it in some time.